# Transfer Array of range rows into consecutive columns in Powerpoint Slide Table

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, slide

I am trying to copy a fixed number of rows of a 2 column range (say sets of 10 rows each time) and paste these rows into the table (e.g. Table 3) of a duplicated template slide's containing 5 columns x 10 rows (excluding header and top row).

**Edit:**

> Forgot to add that i am picking up the ranges into an Array and then
>   trying to paste them. The Array is first sorted in place (By Ref) on
>   1st column using a 2D QuickSort Array procedure.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PasteRangesIntoSlideTables()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim oPPT As Object
Dim oPres As Object
Dim oSlide As Object
Dim Shp As Object
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim RowCnt&, i&, j&
Dim VarRng As Range
Dim Arr
Dim sNo$, sLabel$, NoOfSlides&, sDestPath$

sDestPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Sample Template.pptx"

On Error Resume Next
Set oPPT = GetObject(sDestPath, "Powerpoint.Application")
'On Error GoTo 0

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
End If

If oPPT Is Nothing Then
    Set oPPT = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
End If

If oPPT.presentations.Count > 0 Then
    Set oPres = oPPT.presentations(Dir(sDestPath))
Else
    Set oPres = oPPT.presentations.Open(sDestPath)
End If

With oPPT
    .Visible = True
    For Each oSlide In oPres.slides
        Select Case LCase(Trim(oSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text))
            Case Is = LCase("Template Slide")
                oSlide.Name = "Slide0_TemplateSlide"
            Case Else

        End Select
    Next oSlide


    Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With Sht
        RowCnt = Application.Count(.Columns(1))

        For i = 1 To RowCnt
            Set VarRng = .Columns(1).Cells.Find(what:=i, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            sNo = VarRng.Value2                     ' grab Number
            sLabel = VarRng.Offset(0, 1).Value2 ' grab Label

            If Not VarRng Is Nothing Then
                Set VarRng = .Range(VarRng.Offset(1, 0), VarRng.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1))
                Arr = VarRng.Value2
                QuickSortArray Arr, , , 1

                ' way to split this array to split into 10 rows each time to paste to columns 1 & 2 of slide table.
                ' then next <=10 to paste to columns 4 & 5 of slide table.
                ' If rows exceed 20, then duplicate the template slide `Slide0_TemplateSlide`.
                ' Repeat pasting procedure.
                ' If rows are <=10 then delete unwanted columns 3,4,5 of table to trim it.
                '..........................
                '..........................
                '..........................

                ' No of slides to be duplicated
                NoOfSlides = Int(UBound(Arr, 1) / 20) + IIf(((UBound(Arr, 1) Mod 20 < 20) And (UBound(Arr, 1) Mod 20 > 0)), 1, 0)
                For j = 1 to NoOfSlides
                    With oPres
                        Set oSlide = .slides("Slide0_TemplateSlide").Duplicate
                        With oSlide
                            '....................
                            '....................
                            '....................
                            '....................
                        End With
                    End With
                Next j
            End If
        Next i


    End With
End With

ExitSub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Source: " & Err.Source & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0
Resume ExitSub

End Sub


Sub QuickSortArray(ByRef SortArray As Variant, Optional lngMin As Long = -1, Optional lngMax As Long = -1, Optional lngColumn As Long = 0)
    'Sort a 2-Dimensional array
    ' SampleUsage: sort arrData by the contents of column 3
    '
    '   QuickSortArray arrData, , , 3
    '
    'Posted by Jim Rech 10/20/98 Excel.Programming
    'Modifications, Nigel Heffernan:
    '       ' Escape failed comparison with empty variant
    '       ' Defensive coding: check inputs
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim varMid As Variant
    Dim arrRowTemp As Variant
    Dim lngColTemp As Long

    If IsEmpty(SortArray) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If InStr(TypeName(SortArray), "()") < 1 Then  'IsArray() is somewhat broken: Look for brackets in the type name
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If lngMin = -1 Then
        lngMin = LBound(SortArray, 1)
    End If
    If lngMax = -1 Then
        lngMax = UBound(SortArray, 1)
    End If
    If lngMin >= lngMax Then    ' no sorting required
        Exit Sub
    End If

    i = lngMin
    j = lngMax

    varMid = Empty
    varMid = CLng(Mid(SortArray((lngMin + lngMax) \ 2, lngColumn), 2, Trim(Len(SortArray((lngMin + lngMax) \ 2, lngColumn)))))

    ' We  send 'Empty' and invalid data items to the end of the list:
    If IsObject(varMid) Then  ' note that we don't check isObject(SortArray(n)) - varMid *might* pick up a valid default member or property
        i = lngMax
        j = lngMin
    ElseIf IsEmpty(varMid) Then
        i = lngMax
        j = lngMin
    ElseIf IsNull(varMid) Then
        i = lngMax
        j = lngMin
    ElseIf varMid = "" Then
        i = lngMax
        j = lngMin
    ElseIf VarType(varMid) = vbError Then
        i = lngMax
        j = lngMin
    ElseIf VarType(varMid) > 17 Then
        i = lngMax
        j = lngMin
    End If

    While i <= j
        While CLng(Mid(SortArray(i, lngColumn), 2, Trim(Len(SortArray(i, lngColumn))))) < varMid And i < lngMax
            i = i + 1
        Wend
        While varMid < CLng(Mid(SortArray(j, lngColumn), 2, Trim(Len(SortArray(j, lngColumn))))) And j > lngMin
            j = j - 1
        Wend

        If i <= j Then
            ' Swap the rows
            ReDim arrRowTemp(LBound(SortArray, 2) To UBound(SortArray, 2))
            For lngColTemp = LBound(SortArray, 2) To UBound(SortArray, 2)
                arrRowTemp(lngColTemp) = SortArray(i, lngColTemp)
                SortArray(i, lngColTemp) = SortArray(j, lngColTemp)
                SortArray(j, lngColTemp) = arrRowTemp(lngColTemp)
            Next lngColTemp
            Erase arrRowTemp

            i = i + 1
            j = j - 1
        End If
    Wend

    If (lngMin < j) Then Call QuickSortArray(SortArray, lngMin, j, lngColumn)
    If (i < lngMax) Then Call QuickSortArray(SortArray, i, lngMax, lngColumn)
End Sub
```

There are many such 2 column disjointed ranges in a sheet in columns 1 & 2 only.

So the 1st set of 10 rows will be pasted into Columns 1 & 2 of table. The remaining set of <=10 rows of the range will be pasted into the next 4 & 5 columns (column 3 will be just a separator column). So a single slide table will hold only 20 range rows (10 + 10).

If the range rows exceed 20, e.g. 31, then 20 rows will be pasted into the slide table (as 10 in 1 & 2 columns + 10 rows in 4 & 5 columns) and remaining 11 range rows will be pasted into a similar duplicated 
slide table as 10 rows in 1 & 2 columns and 1 row in 4 & 5 columns. So each time range rows exceed 20, the template slide containing a blank table will be duplicated to be filled.

- I am currently able to pick up the 2 column range from a sheet.
- I am able to determine how many slides to be created from the number of range rows.

**E.g. 4 Slides:**

```
RowCnt = 63   'UBound(Arr, 1)
NoOfSlides = Int(UBound(Arr, 1) / 20) + IIf(((UBound(Arr, 1) Mod 20 < 20) And (UBound(Arr, 1) Mod 20 > 0)), 1, 0)
```

- I am not able to determine how to copy paste 20 rows per slide i.e. 10 rows in 1 & 2 columns and <=10 rows in 4 & 5 columns of slide table.
- I am not able to duplicate slide if range rows exceed 20 rows.
- I am not able to delete unwanted columns 3,4,5 of table if range rows only fill 1 & 2 columns of a table.

Is there someone who has done something like this? I am attaching a [sample xlsx file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m2H64PyIpj7mmqSC7XFEfzU4U8i_Zjo7IXvxp3P6k30/edit?usp=sharing) and [sample powerpoint template](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1szYmwAo7eHyEDLq6u3tEcWFK5iFKdJaH4Q6EV6Z6lO8/edit?usp=sharing) to get an idea of what i am trying to do.

Comment: Please post your VBA code here, enough so that we can reproduce the problem easily. I can't speak for others, but I generally avoid downloading macro-enabled documents from unknown sources.

Comment: @JohnKorchok oh sorry, the workbook by default on my system is saved as xlsm file, but it doesn't contain macros. I will try to add some snippets of code to get a clear idea.

Comment: @JohnKorchok, i have quickly written and added some code to demonstrate what i am trying to achieve. I have also reuploaded an xlsx file which doesnt contain the code, but has the data unsorted. Let me know if anything is unclear. Thanks.

Comment: Does anyone know how to write to a Slide table from an Array?